# Why can't a computed property be accessed as namespace?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've found an issue in AS3 namespace indexing nearly a month ago.

First, my test:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class main extends MovieClip {

        /* Namespace definition */
        protected namespace Demo;
        Demo const AMOUNT = 0;


        public function main() {
            super();

            /* Put the namespace inside a property */
            const obj = {
                Demo: Demo
            };

            /* Now namespace-index this property */
            trace((obj.Demo)::AMOUNT);
            /* The following fails: obj.Demo::AMOUNT,
             * it's aproximately obj::AMOUNT */
        }
    }

}
```

It works as expected, outputing `0`. But when I want to compute the get resolver `obj.Demo`, it throws an error (it's not English, but: <sub>`1043: Espacio de nombres no definido`</sub>), or <sub>`Namespace not defined`</sub>:

```
trace((obj['Demo'])::AMOUNT);
```

I'd like to know the reason (and `obj['Demo']::AMOUNT` results in a syntax error).

Comment: really strange: consider `var d = obj['Demo'];
   trace(d::AMOUNT);`, even `var c;
   trace((c = obj['Demo'])::AMOUNT);`.

Comment: @www0z0k Yes, these ways it works. I've tried them! However I don't find reason on why `(obj['Demo'])::AMOUNT` doesn't work, the behavior.

Comment: I'm preparing ideas for a compiler, so... If this is a bug, then I can simply correct it